# Is it possible to add In app billing feature to my free android app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

I have a free app running on google play store.
I want to add In-app billing feature in my application.But still I want to keep my app free(i.e.,Not paid apps).So is it possible.I have google merchant account.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in-app billing but if you have existing users you will not want to restrict features that are already available to them for free.  The usual use of in-app billing is to have a free app with a basic tier of features that remain free indefinitely, and then to create a value-added tier of features that can be accessed by making an in-app payment.  If you deviate from that model by charging for features that people were told they could obtain free, then you will have lots of angry users and bad reviews.  I don't know whether Google would also look askance at it, but the effect on users should be enough to make you avoid it.

The one exception would be if you offer a timed free trial up front, and all of your users were told from the start that the trial would expire and could only be continued by making an in-app payment.

Yes, you have to worry about Google's policies, but treating your users well should be just as important, and will certainly affect the perception of your app.

Comment: Thanks Carl for this important information.In future also I don't want to charge any amount on my app.

Comment: @MDFAIZANWAR if you like this answer and has been solve your question then accept it otherwise you should atleast upvote(+1) the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think there is but it needs evualated/approved  by Google before you can use it